# How can I calculate a group wise total in a silverlight datagrid?

Tags: silverlight-3.0, datagrid

I want group wise sub Total and at the end grand total

please provide some sample code for the same

For Example

```
Group  ItemID  Price  qty  total   
1         1      5     2    10
          2      3     3     9
                           ------
                            19 
2
          2      3     3     9

                           ------
                             9
                           ------
```

Answer (score 0):

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/119135/330661.aspx

Check this link I have posted the solution in the last.. hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to achieve the same functionality. 
So far i have managed to found the following examples (works for silverlight 4)

[Summary row in DataGrid](http://leeontech.wordpress.com/2010/02/01/summary-row-in-datagrid/)

[Summary rows in Datagrid with multiple groups](http://leeontech.wordpress.com/2010/03/25/summary-rows-in-datagrid-with-multiple-groups/)